# Filter a pandas df based on some rules in a yaml file

Tags: python, pandas, yaml

I have a configuration yaml file that is supposed to be used by customers and be easy to edit. In the yaml file there are some rules:

```
variables:
  used_often: ['good','bad', 3]

rules:
  - dataframe_name: my_name
    variables: 
      consequence: used_often
    query: 'column_a = 5 and column_b in ${consequence} and column_c != 1'
    output: {'column_d': 1}
  - more rules like this
```

As you can see here I want to filter 3 columns in the df `my_name` where `column_a = 5` etc. and then in the result of this filter add/change `column_d` so that all rows that matched the query have `column_d = 1`.

My question is how could I make the query more easy to be filtered with pandas. As it stands, the query above should end up in pandas like this:

```
my_name[(my_name["column_a"] == 5) &
 (my_name["column_b"].isin(['good','bad', 3])) &
 (my_name["column_c"] != 1)]
```

So I have to do a lot of processing to interpret the query in yaml. Are there any tools that could help me or better ways to format the query (I have complete freedom in building the yaml file as long as it is reasonable easy for a client to write it)?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand yaml file. Can you change the query statement in your yaml file? If you can, then you could set the query statement the same as the dataframe condition. For example `query: (my_name["column_a"] == 5) &
 (my_name["column_b"].isin(['good','bad', 3])) &
 (my_name["column_c"] != 1)`.

Comment: @MohitMotwani yes, but then it will be like asking the client to write code in yaml. I was looking for something easier for the client. He will have to know .isin() and other pandas functions...

Comment: You want to process a yaml file into python code. As @MohitMotwani shows you, you could just have the client write the actual code. This won't work, you say, because your client needs something easier. This is the main problem with the question because at the end of the day, you know your client and we don't. We can assume that the easier the yaml file is for the client, the more preprocessing you will have to do. I flagged your question as primarily opinion-based because of this.

Comment: @user3471881I would imagine yaml rules to filter dfs are not that uncommon and maybe somebody developed a tool that will help..

Comment: Then the question becomes off-topic: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @user3471881it's not recommending a tool, it is solving a problem, I thought this is clear from my question

Answer (score 1):

There is a pandas.query function that does all that https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

So my query in yaml becomes:

```
query: 'column_a == 5 and column_b in @consequence and column_c !=1'
```

and then in python I can read the yaml and filter:

```
df.query(my_query)
```